# how can i create vcproj (VSC++ project file ) from nmake file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, projects, nmake

i have project that supply me only the nmake files , and i like to load the project to Visual studio express 9 , how can convert the nmake to vaild vcproj files ?

Comment: The retail edition has the Makefile project template.  Sooner or later you discover that your time is worth money too.

Answer (score 1):

One of the easisest way of creating a Visual Studio project from existing code is going to the *New->Project from Exisiting Code* menu item and following the wizard.  This won't actually create the project from the data in the nmake file, but its a nice start.